# How to load palette to image using java(Can any one please help)

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I want apply palette  to images which are opened.

Currently i am using an VB Application which is having capacity of only 300 images and as i am sending key strokes to **paint shop pro** I can't do any other work till this process completes.

I am Thinking can it be possible to open 1000 images using java and Load an Palette i.e JASC-PAL **default.pal** to all the images and close.

Please suggest me the best way.

Thanks in Advanced...

Comment: Hi all, Can any one suggest me some solution.

Comment: Hi No one can help me for my Query....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're interested in is applying the palette to a batch of files and it doesn't necessarily need to be part of some Java-based process, then you might find a program called IrfanView useful: http://www.irfanview.com/

Someone asked the same question on their forums and apparently it's quite easy to do from the command line: http://en.irfanview-forum.de/vb/showthread.php?4246-Batch-Import-of-Palette-file

Mind that the tool is free for non-commercial use. Make sure your usage doesn't violate this agreement. If you're using this in a commercial manner (e.g. at your workplace or in the context of your job), obtain a license. A single one costs, like, $12. So you'd be crazy not to make that little contribution.

I'm not affiliated with IrfanView in any way nor is it my intention to promote here. I'm just offering the most straightforward solution I found while searching. Didn't take me long, so you might find something else quite easily.